# Is there a way to map a certain type of data from all source files in a directory to a memory section in a linker command file without being explicit?

Tags: c, gcc, linker, gnu, ld

I am using the GNU toolchain for an ARM project that I am working on.  The project includes a real-time operating system (RTOS) and utilizes the memory protection unit (MPU) of the ARM Cortex-R4 CPU.

I am using a linker command (`.ld`) file to map `.bss` and `.data` sections to blocks of memory that can made available to tasks that require access.

This particular application has several different build configurations.  The project has two top-level source code folders, which for all intents and purposes I will call `common` and `custom`.  Folder `common` contains all of the source code used by all build configurations and folder `custom` contains one subfolder for each build configuration containing the source code specific to that build configuration.  For example, `custom/build_cfg1`, `custom/build_cfg2`, etc.

All of the `custom` source code is called from a single RTOS task.  I would like to set up the linker file to be able to place all `.data` and `.bss` sections from the `custom` folder into a single section based on the file location, but the approach that I am using is not catching the `.data` and `.bss` sections.  The following is an example of what the linker command file looks like:

```
    .custom_bss (NOLOAD) : AT (0)
    {
        custom_bss_start = .;
        "./custom/*" (.bss.*)
        custom_bss_end = .;
    }

    /* Define initialized data separately since it must be loaded. */
    .custom_data : AT(ld_custom_data_load_addr)
    {
        custom_data_start = .;
        "./custom/*" (.data.*)
        custom_data_end = .;
    }
```

A few things to note:

- I have verified that the file path passed to the linker begins with `./custom/` and that the `.data` and `.bss` sections are being mapped to catch-all `.data` and `.bss` sections.
- Source files in the `common` folder have already been mapped as needed.
- I have configured my builder to only include the files for the active build configuration when compiling and linking.
- Sections are specified using `.bss.*` and `.data.*`, since I am using the `-fdata-sections` option when compiling.

Is there a technique for specifying the filename that will allow me to map all `.bss` and `.data` sections from a folder and its subfolders to a particular section using the linker command file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After investigating further, I found that there was actually a problem with the way that I defined the input section (.bss) instead of (.bss.*).  Once this was corrected, `./custom/*/*.o (.bss.*)` was able to pull in .bss sections from source files in subdirectories and subdirectories of subdirectories of `custom`.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

From `ld` documrntation:

> Wildcards only match files which are explicitly specified on the
> command line. The linker does not search directories to expand
> wildcards.

I would do it another way. Write a simple program and run it before build adding the files explicitly (or at least directories). Easy to archive in make, cmake or eclipse.

Comment: Thanks for taking a moment to answer.  I also saw this on the linker documentation page (https://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/ld-2.9.1/html_chapter/ld_3.html#SEC23), but it seemed a bit vague, so I was hoping that there was a trick to it.  Turns out that it works the way that I originally did it, I just made a mistake in specifying the input section (.bss instead of .bss.*).